# Can not publish post of Wordpress 3.5.2 using XMLRPC

Tags: c#, wordpress

I've use the XMLRPC to post a thread to the Wordpress (3.5.2) here is my code:

```
public string newPost(string title, string content, string[] categoryIds)
    {
        this.Url = this.url ;
        Post post = new Post();
        post.post_date = DateTime.Now;
        post.post_title = title;
        post.post_content = content;
        post.post_status = "publish";

        XmlRpcStruct terms = new XmlRpcStruct();
        terms.Add("category", categoryIds);
        post.terms = terms;

        return newPost("0", this.username, this.password, post, true);
    }
    [XmlRpcMethod("wp.newPost ")]
    public string newPost(string blogId, string username, string password, Post content, bool pubish)
    {
        string s = "";
        try
        {
            s = (string)this.Invoke("newPost", new object[] { blogId, username, password, content, pubish });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            s = ex.Message;
        }
        return s;
    }
```

But when I check that post from adnin, it's show "Scheduled"

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wordpress installation is configured with a difference timezone than your publishing client workstation. This is causing the post to come in with a future date (from the perspective of WP), which marks it with a scheduled status rather than publishing it immediately. Make sure you've set your wp installation timezone correctly (Example, if you live in PST GMT-8 zone, use the "America/Los Angeles" setting so it can calculate daylight savings).

Edit: you have a typo in your method parameter named "pubish" rather than "publish"

Comment: Thank you! I've fixed this prolem few hours ago :-)

Comment: No problem, I ran into and solved the same issue just before I saw your post.